# sklearn-porter export() throws MemoryError

Tags: out-of-memory

I'm trying to export my `RandomForestClassifier` model into Java using `sklearn-porter` and it runs out of memory.  How can I get past this issue?  The Linux process grows to about 10+G and then fails - the machine has 24G available.

The training set has ~ 2.5M elements and is likely to increase in size as we target more classes to classify. The model has 20 features (can be potentially reduced). Currently we have let the trees grow as deep as possible.  I'd hate to restrict the depth of the trees to get it to export to Java.

Related post: [Darius Morawiec's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215302/10128148) in [Exporting python sklearn models to production (java/c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651643/exporting-python-sklearn-models-to-production-java-c)

Code:

```
# train the forest
rfcf.fit(x_train, y_train)

# export
porter = Porter(rfcf, language='java')
output = porter.export(embed_data=True)
print(output)
```

BTW, I am retrying now after bumping up the machine memory to 52GB.

Update:  It failed again with MemoryError after running for ~30 min.

BTW, I should also add that the same model was successfully exported in the verbose PMML format via sklean2pmml on a machine with 24G RAM.  Pickling the model was also achieved in reasonable time (~30 min) but those files are pretty big (2-6 GB.)

Comment: can you add the code / model and the data ?

Comment: That's an interesting bug and requirement. How many trees do you use (see `n_estimators = 10`)? And how deep are your trees (see `max_depth = None`)? Can you provide a dummy models to reproduce that behaviour? Nevertheless I will fix this in a future release.